# Spark Scala - reducebykey => how to get element second of value array?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to calculate sum distance by person over several trips on spark 2.1 and Scala.

I have a pairedRDD with key being the persons, and the list , the list of trip : (sex, nb of km) :

[image]

I would like to add up the number of km by key, I need to access the second value (nb of km) but I don't find how.
I tried : 
[image]

and even simpler : [image]

I am new to scala, and coming from python I don"t get it :-/

## Edit 1

Trying suggested solution : 
[image]

## Edit 2

[image]

## Edit 3

and sample of joinedrdd (I am feeling like I am mixing my variable names a bit : 
[image]

## Edit 4

I don't get it : a and b seems to be transparent to the system : 
The 3 following instructions give the same result : 
[image]

## Edit 5

[image]

Comment: I edited the question to show some joined_rdd data  -joinedrdd is an alias to  'trajets_par_cycliste'

Comment: The pair `(sex, nb of km)` is nesting in level 3 of `rdd`.

Comment: ... how would you fetch it then ?

Comment: give an error : alue reduceByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[List[(String, String)]]

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way :

```
trajets_par_cycliste.map(x => (x._1 , x._2.map({case (k,v) => v.toDouble}).sum)).take(3)
```

[image]